# Expand a div height from set height to natural height on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a div, and inside that div I have a variety of elements (p, strong, a, etc.) - by default this parent div is going to be at 200px height. When I click a read more button (last child element of the parent div) - I want the div to expand to it's natural height. 
I'm using CSS max-height and overflow:hidden to accomplish the effect of a smaller than natural div and hiding the overflowing elements. 
I need to accomplish this with javascript and jquery - and no external libraries unless someone can explain to me how to properly reference them in my wordpress site.

I was using [this tutorials solution](https://css-tricks.com/text-fade-read-more/) and it works fantastically, except that because I have multiple P tags inside the parent div, it won't expand to the full height of said parent div - thus my question.

EDIT: After some more time working at it, here's a really good solution, that also includes animation. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/57fxjLyf/).

```
$('.career-readMore').on('click', function(event) {
var container = $(this).parent();
$(container).toggleClass('expanded');
$(container).css('max-height', '3000px');
```

Comment: show us your code, or online example if possible

Comment: Agree! Show us some code

Comment: Here is the code. For some reason it "expands" upwards in the codepen.
[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdJPBe)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/smo5vz67/

Assuming the structure presented in the fiddle, the solution is as simple as:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.read-more').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('expanded');
    });
});
```

plus some CSS

```
.container{
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height:200px;
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid #999;
}

.container.expanded{
    max-height:none;
}

.read-more{
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: This works great. How might one animate the height change?

Comment: @lime517 you can use ```transition: max-height 0.2s linear``` on the container class

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$('#btnExpand').click(function(){
    $('#target').css('height', 'inherit');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aznpqud0/

Comment: This also works great - is it possible to animate the height change?

Comment: You can use jquery animate but you'd have to set a static height not use inherit